# Which Oracle ODBC driver biztalk uses if there is more than one installed?

Tags: oracle, biztalk

I'm wondering how WCF-OracleDB receive adapter distinguishes drivers installed in OS.
I have 2 oracle driver folders in OS both with 32/64bit version of it and I think maybe one is totally spare - How can I check that to be sure that I can delete one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If the Host of the Host Instance associated to the Receive Location is 32bit-Only, then the 32bit driver.

Otherwise, 64.

Comment: Note: The BizTalk Admin console is always 32bit.  Which is why you need to have both versions of adapters installed.  Not sure if this would apply to the ODBC drivers as well.

Comment: @felixmondelo But I have two drivers (two pairs 32 and 64 bit)  installed into a system - how to recognize which is used by Biztalk?